# check xml attributes & append elements with Python 3.4

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I want to iterate through the child-elements of and element and check their attributes. If a certain attribute value is missing it should append an empty element with that attribute value.

So to this:

```
<app>        
    <rdg wit="#W_1956">Im Restaurant </rdg>               
    <rdg wit="#W_2002">Im Restaurant </rdg>
    <rdg wit="#W_2010">Im Restaurant </rdg>
</app>
```

I want to add an element

```
<rdg wit="#W_1999"/>
```

My Python code looks like this:

```
for app in root.findall('app'):
    if  '#W_1956' not in ET.Element('rdg').attrib:
        new_tag = ET.SubElement(app, 'rdg')

        new_tag.attrib['wit'] = '#W_1956' 
    if  '#W_1999' not in ET.Element('rdg').attrib:
        new_tag = ET.SubElement(app, 'rdg')

        new_tag.attrib['wit'] = '#W_1999'
```

Which gives me this XML:

```
<app>        
    <rdg wit="#W_1956">Im Restaurant </rdg>
    <rdg wit="#W_2002">Im Restaurant </rdg>
    <rdg wit="#W_2010">Im Restaurant </rdg>
    <rdg wit="#W_1956"/>
    <rdg wit="#W_1999"/>
</app>
```

So even though there is an Element with the W_1956 attribute in the source it adds it anyway. I also tried findall('rdg') instead but that doesn't work either (the output XML remains completely unchanged). Now I have no idea if the mistake is in the if-statement, somewhere in the elementree-(sub)elements or if the code is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a explicit attribute. For example:

```
.
.
.
if  '#W_1956' not in ET.Element('rdg').attrib['wit']
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider conditionally checking from the document's entire list of `rgd` attributes by saving into separate lists. Then, iteratively check values to add or not add new elements, all using the fact that `etree`'s parsing renders XML attributes as Python dictionaries with key/value pairings.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

txt ='''<app>        
    <rdg wit="#W_1956">Im Restaurant </rdg>               
    <rdg wit="#W_2002">Im Restaurant </rdg>
    <rdg wit="#W_2010">Im Restaurant </rdg>
</app>'''

root = ET.fromstring(txt)

# LIST OF ALL ATTRIBUTE DICTS
attrdict = [app.attrib for app in root.findall('./rdg')]
# LIST OF ALL ATTRIBUTE VALUES
attrvals = [v for i in attrdict for k,v in i.items()]

# ITERATE THROUGH ATTRIB VALUES AND ADD TO ROOT IF DOES NOT EXIST
for i in ['#W_1956', '#W_1999']:
    if  i not in attrvals:
        new_tag = ET.SubElement(root, 'rdg')
        new_tag.attrib['wit'] = i

# OUTPUT TO STRING
print(ET.tostring(root).decode('UTF-8'))
# <app>        
#    <rdg wit="#W_1956">Im Restaurant </rdg>               
#    <rdg wit="#W_2002">Im Restaurant </rdg>
#    <rdg wit="#W_2010">Im Restaurant </rdg>
# <rdg wit="#W_1999" /></app>

# OUTPUT TO FILE
ET.ElementTree(root).write('myoutput.xml', encoding="UTF-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

Comment: Thank you but this adds the rdg-tags in the root not as children of the app tag
 '    <app>
        <rdg>...
    </app>
    <rdg wit="#W_1956"/>
    <rdg wit="#W_1999"/>
'

Comment: Look closer. The etree output does not pretty print with indentation properly at the end but tag is added to child of *app*.